# Retrieve QueryString And Force Custom Url To A Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, routes

I am trying to config custom url in the RouteConfig.cs file as follows with the default one:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute( 
            name: "Default2",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/id/{id}", //Custom url route
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "AddImages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The above works fine when I write the followings in the url: **1st routing**

```
http://localhost:1234/Product/AddImages/id/1008
```

Again, the below also works: **2nd routing**

```
http://localhost:1234/Product/AddImages/1008
```

But I want to force the url to show or write the url in the address bar as the first one for the specific page 'AddImages' like this: http://localhost:1234/Product/AddImages/id/1008

Is there any way to do it I mean keeping the default routing and for a specific page, the first routing option?

Again, I tried to retrieve the QueryString from the first url as follows:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]); //This works for the second routing option
```

It says - **Input string wasn't in a correct format**. I guess, this is for the default routing option as it's configured to:

```
 url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Again, is it possible to get the QueryString value from the below url or to config anything:

```
http://localhost:1234/Product/AddImages/id/1008
```

Comment: Your routes are in the wrong order - `Default2` needs to be first (before `Default`)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I was able to resolve by ordering the routing. Thanks to you and brainless coder for the ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In routing table for MVC, the route that are defined first has the highest priority. So all you need is make sure your specific route higher priority than the default one. Just define it earlier. That is it - as mentioned in the comment.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "Default2",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/id/{id}", //Custom url route
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "AddImages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you want only the first one then try removing the generic one

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "Default2",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/id/{id}", //Custom url route
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "AddImages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

If you want it only for that controller only try this  -

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "Default2",
        url: "Product/{action}/id/{id}", //Custom url route
        defaults: new { action = "AddImages", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { controller = "Product" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

There is a better way to get url parameters. Instead of

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]); //
```

try this -

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["id"]); //
```

But if you defined your action method properly, you don't even need to read it from request. It will automatically be mapped.

Comment: brainless coder! Thanks for the solution. I am
not able to get the values from querystring like
this: /AddImages/id/2. But it works well for
this: /AddImages/2. Is there any way to get
the custom url value? I tried your solution but
didn't work I mean not getting the value. By the way, the constraint doesn't force the controller to the specific url. Is there anything to configure?

Comment: @AT-2016 I don't remember, it has been long since I used explicit routes, I usually use attribute routes, I will test and update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll be waiting. Basically I am willing to get the url or QueryString value from this routing: /AddImages/id/2 (Custom routing). I am not sure if this is possible. If it's, then I can handle the rest.

Comment: I was able to resolve it. Thanks for letting know about the constraints. Now I am aware of it. This is what I've done and forced the url that I preferred: routes.MapRoute("Default2", "{controller}/{action}/imageId/{id}", new { controller = "Product", action = "AddImages", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" });